# What's the name of the color printed section in a book?

Tags: single-word-requests

Before books were routinely full color, there would be a section of full color pages bound into the middle of the book.

What's the name for this section?

Comment: Are you sure there is a name for it? In books with such sections, there would often be a list of those sections at the front, but it would just say "List of Illustrations".

Comment: I believe there is a name, and I thought it was *colorplate*, but I looked it up, and apparently I'm wrong.

Comment: They're referred to as "plates", but I think that refers to the individual color pages rather than the entire section of them.

Comment: @GregLee, that's an acceptable answer if you can provide a reference.  I don't actual care if the name applies to each page or the section as a whole.

Comment: I googled "color plates in books", and the very first reference from Abe Books says "Most people familiar with AbeBooks will have seen the words ‘color plate’ used in association with certain rare book listings. Plates are whole page illustrations printed separately from the text (illustrations printed within the text are called cuts) and naturally color plates feature color illustrations."

Comment: By the way, in the reference I mentioned, http://www.abebooks.com/books/rare-colour-illustrations-cuts-rackham/color-plates.shtml, there is a listing of beautiful color plates in old books.  The third book shown, **Moths and Butterflies of the United States East of the Rocky Mountains**, brings back memories of my two year obsession with collecting moths and butterflies when I was young.  I ran across this book in my local library down in the dusty old basement stacks.

Comment: I can remember a colour plate at the front of a book being described as a *frontispiece*. The Oxford Dictionary Online defines it as *an illustration facing the title page of a book*. I am afraid I know of no such name for those in the centre of a book.

Comment: My recollection is "color plates".

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I would agree with that.

Comment: @WS2, well, I thought that too, but it wasn't obvious if that was right from a quick Google search.

Comment: Yet another term for such as section is "color insert." This is not as formal a name as "tipped-in pages [or _plates_]"; but it is widely used on the editing (as opposed to binding) side of the publishing process.

Answer (score 15):

## [(Tipped-in) (color) plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipped-in_page)

Partial quote from Wikipedia:

> In the book trade, a **tipped-in page** or, if it is an illustration, **tipped-in plate** or simply **plate**, is a page that is printed separately from the main text of the book, but attached to the book.[1]
>
> A tipped-in page may be glued onto a regular page, or even bound along with the other pages. It is often printed on a different kind of paper, using a different printing process, and of a different format than a regular page.
>
> [...]
>
> Typical uses of tipped-in pages added by the publisher include:
>
> - **color illustrations, generally printed using a different process (e.g. intaglio or lithography) and on different paper**
> - an author's signature, signed on a blank or preprinted page, before the book is bound
> - original photographic prints
> - maps, often larger than the book format and folded to fit
> - coupons or reply cards
> - errata sheets, only produced after the printing run
> - a short addendum
> - a replacement for a missing, damaged, or incorrectly printed page

As implied above, more colloquially, they can be called simply **color plates** or just **plates**.

Comment: I never understand these things. Doubtless the most technical answer, but how many non-printers use it or are going to be helped by 'tipped in'? Why isn't 'color section', in standard English, the most upvoted answer? It is the name for the section (as OP requests) rather than a half-page of the section.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This already also includes **color plate** or just **plate** as possible less technical answers.   I've just edited to make this more explicit.

Comment: Perhaps you should donate the upvotes to those who came up with it first.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, perhaps you should read the history carefully and see that I came up with it first.  My initial guess was 'colorplate', it didn't seem right because the first Google search didn't bear it out.     In addition some of the comments have been deleted.   Greg's confirmation of my thought allowed me to locate the Wikipedia page which provides the reference.

Comment: 'Colorplate'? 'I looked it up, and apparently I'm wrong.' Greg Lee seems to have suggested the simplex and open compound nouns. Voting is almost bound to be an imperfect method to show approval, but I'm convinced that the disproportionate numbers some basic answers get is not good for the credibility of the site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth:   Well, Edwin, if you don't accept I already had the answer, maybe you should think about whether you think the voting should be about the quality of the answer and not who found it.   Usually after people gain significant rep (I have over 10k on another site), people move into the philosophy that the goal is high-quality answers and not personal reputation.   I don't know you because I'm not very active on *this* site, but I'm surprised that you don't hold this opinion given your 33k rep. Yes, Greg had a part in helping confirm this answer, but I added significantly more info.

Comment: 'Tipped-in color plate' belongs on a reprographics site. 'Color section' belongs on ELL. And 'color plate', 'plate' and 'tipped-in color plate' don't answer your question 'What's the name for this **section**?' as Greg Lee points out.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, first of all, I clarified that **color plates** is an acceptable answer, right away.   That is a name for the **section** even if one is plural and the other is singular.   What's the name of this section?  It's the color plates.  That is the answer I was looking for.   That's the answer that's most useful to me.   As OP I have that sovereignty.   If you don't like it, you can ask a different question.

Comment: 'maybe you should think about whether you think the voting should be about the quality of the answer and not who found it.' That's the **only** criterion I consider justifiable. Please have a look at John Lawler's answer on [parallel structure in sentences](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291524/parallel-structure-in-sentences) and compare it with offering 'color plates' as a term linguists need to be reminded of, or the jargon 'tipped in color plates' as a term which will greatly help the majority of English linguists. Then comment on the voting patterns here.

Answer (score 5):

Old (and even some new) wildlife guides used to use this format, with species descriptions printed on Bible paper and photos or other colour representations on colour plates. This seems to be true in other techincal texts where full-colour printing of the entire book would be too expensive.

Rather boringly when the plates are referred to collectively, the term "plate section" is used. More often the photos would be referred to as a "photo(graph) section", or (especially when reproduced from paintings) just "colour section".

Examples (from online sources):

- "The ... reference point in any field guide is the plate section"

  *A Field Guide to Birds of the Gambia and Senegal*, Barlow, Wacher & Disley.  (via [Google books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?isbn=0300115741))
- "For a colour version of this figure please see colour plate section"

  *Radiotherapy in Practice - Brachytherapy*, Hoskin & Coyle (via [Google books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?isbn=0199600902))

Comment: I think I've got some examples on the shelf. I'll hopefully edit in some usage examples /references.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tipped-in+plate%2Ccolor+section&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccolor%20section%3B%2Cc0) show that 'color section' is a far more popular / less jargonistic term.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thank you.  "Plate section" was above "colo[u]r section" until about 1960, but of course "colour section" can refer to other things (e.g. newspapers).

Answer (score 1):

Those are the *[glossy pages](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/G/glossy_paper.html)*.

Back when people used Sears catalogs as toilet paper, you'd hope to get a new one before you had to start using the *glossy pages*.

Comment: Dunno, my Grandpa might have gone straight for the glossy pages. His preferred loo roll was weird, my best description is to compare it to greaseproof paper!

Answer (score 0):

Its called a (colour) plate section. They are a multiple of 32 pages (sometimes 16). They will also only occur after a multiple of 32 pages – it is to do with how the book is printed and bound (one giant page is folded until you get 32 sides). Printing a whole book in colour is expensive, just doing one section in colour saves money.